# How to get a function's name from a object passed as that function's parameter in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say, I have a function named ***my_function*** and I'm passing an object as its parameter in the following way:

```
my_obj = MyClass()

my_function(my_obj)
```

Is there a way using which I can print the name of the function inside a method of MyClass?

Let's say that MyClass has a method called ***display_info*** inside it and it prints the name of the function in where the object of MyClass is passed.

An example would be:

```
class MyClass:

    def print_log(self):
        # some code


    def random_method_1():
        pass

    def random_method_2():


def my_function(param1, some_name, some_number):
    # some code

# Instantiating MyClass
my_object = MyClass()

# Calling my_function
my_function(my_object, "John Doe", 38478347)

my_object.print_log()
# Above line of code should be able to print "my_function"
```

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean. How it's to be used and what result you expect.

Comment: The answer is basically no, but I don't really understand your question.  When do you intend this to be printed?  Do you want `my_function(my_obj)` to result in "my_function" being printed?  If so, why not just do that inside `my_function`?

Comment: I think @bakkal has a great answer for you, I would like to point out that it sounds like you are creating a "weird machine" that will have "side effects". This is quite bad practice. Maybe you have a good motivation for wanting this design, but in general, I would say your problem is architectural, not programmatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Design your program better

If you need this systematically you might want a better designed program, e.g. one that injects the name of the parent or calling entity into e.g. `my_obj.display_info(caller='something')`

```
class MyClass:
    def display_info(self, caller):
        print caller

def my_function(my_obj):
    my_obj.display_info(caller='my_function')
```

The above allows that param to be injected by each caller.

Or keep a reference to the caller in `MyClass.caller` at init time if possible, or set it on the spot as needed e.g.

```
# pseudo code
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, caller):
        self.caller = caller

   def display_info(self):
        print self.caller

my_obj = MyClass(caller='caller')
my_obj.display_info()

my_obj.caller = 'new_caller'
my_obj.display_info()
```

### The `inspect` hack to avoid

> The [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) provides several useful functions to help get
>   information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods,
>   functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects.

Yes usng `inspect`. When you call `inspect.stack()` you get a record of frame objects. So we use `stack()[1]` to get the previous frame, which is a tuple where the third element is the name of the caller (my_function). Hence `stack()[1][3]`.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class MyClass():
...     def display_info(self):
...         print inspect.stack()[1][3]
... 
>>> def my_function(my_obj):
...     my_obj.display_info()
... 
>>> my_obj = MyClass()
>>> my_function(my_obj)
my_function   # <--- The result you wanted
>>> 
>>> def another_fn(my_obj):
...     my_obj.display_info()
... 
>>> another_fn(my_obj)
another_fn
```

This provides the result you want (prints the name of the calling function)